# Sql procedure to compare records from one table to other and insert the missing, delete not existing and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, procedure

I'm beginner working with SQL.

I have the below required, kindly help. Database - SQL Server.

I have 2 tables, so called AA & BB, I wanted to have a procedure that would compare BB to AA against all the columns (column name and data type of the column is same) and then do the following:

1. insert records in the table AA if the records is missing which exist in BB
2. If the records that was existing on AA is not longer in BB then a column 'comments' needed to updated with the text 'No longer available'
3. For the existing records on AA, if the value of any column in changed in BB when compared against then it should update the record in AA and enter a 'comment' column that 'Column ABC updated'.

Your advice or if a working procedure would be given then it would be of great help.

Comment: Sql server database

Comment: Google these seperatly: `Exists()`... `intersect()`...`sys.tables`...`spaghettidba how to ask`

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: You should look into using MERGE. It is designed for this type of thing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql With the exception of the strange requirement of updating a column stating which column was updated. How do you propose handling multiple column updates?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you've tried? Perhaps a more tangible example of your use case? I'm also a bit confused because you mentioned comparing column names and data types, followed by adding missing records. The former is schema information while the latter is row data.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean Lange stated you need to use a MERGE statement for the 1,2,3 actions, check MS documentation on syntax in his comment. As to comparing column names... you can query the information_schema.columns table as so:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'AA';
```

Which will give you each column name as an individual string, use this table to collect column names from both tables and then compare.